# Measuring async/await overhead

Tags: c#, database, async

A while ago I read an article stating that overhead of an async/await call was around 50ms. More recently I read an article that it was around 5ms. I was having a discussion about whether we should standardize async operations for all DB access and decided to take a crack at measuring it myself. And I ended up adding the following methods to a controller:

```
private int profileIterations = 1000;
[HttpGet]
public long NonAsyncLoop()
{
    var timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < profileIterations; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5);
    }
    timer.Stop();
    return timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<long> AsyncLoop()
{
    var timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < profileIterations; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5);
    }
    timer.Stop();
    return timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}
```

This test returns surprisingly regular results indicating that the overhead of calling await Task.Delay() vs Thread.Sleep() is ~1/3 of a ms. Does anyone have any other easy test that could indicate the overhead? Because below 10ms of overhead it becomes a no-brainer to standardize async operations for all DB access.

The other devs and I are deciding about whether to just use async for all DB operations going forward, the app we're working with has all synchronous DB IO, so there is a possibility we may be converting large amounts of existing access when the opportunity arises.

To get an idea of DB latency I'm looking at app insights request profiles and looking at items listed under "SQL (Azure Database) Activities". Most of these "activities" show wait times of between 1 and 5ms. So if my test is roughly accurate, then using async/await for all DB access is clearly the way to go moving forward, and existing synchronous access should be converted whenever practical. However, if overhead is in the 5-50ms range, then using async would actually decrease thread availability while making response time slower simultaneously.

Comment: What routine database operation over a network do you know of that takes less than 100ms?  At 50ms for an async/await call, it's a wash, because *the underlying thread is freed up to do other work during the remaining 50ms.*

Comment: Where you might be remembering 50ms from is that's what Microsoft states as their recommended threshold for making a method asynchronous.  See https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/ui-guidelines-for-async.html

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/38118051

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?  It's not clear to me what the source of this overhead would be aside from the event loop.  Perhaps you misunderstood?  As Robert Harvey points out with thresholds, the point of asyncio is to avoid blocking on IO.  But if your IO is super-fast, it could be finished long before the loop comes back around for the response.  That might be OK if you are waiting on multiple responses, though.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - It depends on your network setup. Last time I looked at our app profiling in Azure I was pretty sure it was indicating to me that there were a lot of DB reads happening in the single digit ms range. Also, my test (if valid) would indicate that the 50ms threshold is silly, and that the idea that DB operations don't have to be async is no longer valid.

Comment: This is an article that measures await overhead ~5ms: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/the-net-4-5-asyncawait-feature-in-promise-and-practice/#:~:text=As%20explained%20in%20the%20introduction,methods%20release%20threads%20while%20waiting

Comment: @JimmyJames - I suppose I assumed that the 50ms threshold was in some way related to overhead and that awaiting requires at least some processing power on the part of the application. But yes, I understand the point of using async/await.

Comment: Let me ask you this very politely, Ian ... *"Why do you – as (of course) a professional software engineer – feel that you actually need to care about this?"* If you're "accessing a database," isn't *that* going to involve far more "inherent timing uncertainty" than you are quibbling about here? "Overhead" really matters only if it prevents you from being able to do something that you really need to be able to do at the time. Such that it actually makes a difference. With utter and complete respect to you, sir, I very simply do not ***yet*** see the cause of your present concern. Please tell me

Comment: While async/await happens to be really low overhead, the general concern isn't invalid. Even a small overhead when multiplied by a large number of occurences (think function calls, dynamic method dispatches, hash map look ups, etc.) can lead to "death by a thousand cuts". Recently we decreased the average response time for my company's web API over 50ms just by implementing connection pooling. "But TCP handshakes are fast" you would think. Well, when there's several layers of CDNs, proxies and ingresses, piled on top of SSL handshake overhead, it turned out to be really sizeable! Surprise!

Comment: Even worse, death-by-a-thousand-cuts type things aren't noticable through profiling because: 1) They might run so quickly that a sampling profiler *doesn't even register that they happened, at all* or 2) their latency impact could be misattributed, e.g. "This drawing subroutine being called repeatedly in the render loop is slow" would make you think it's the drawing code itself is slow, and not that perhaps the dynamic method dispatch or (in an extreme case) the static function dispatch is adding unacceptable overhead.

Comment: If async/await turns out to be unacceptably slow for you (by whatever critieria you have), what would you do instead? I guess you could do synchronous blocking calls if you're okay with tying up threads for long periods of times, but IDK of any domains where such a small latency improvement would be worth such a massive cost in CPU cores.

Comment: The question has been edited to provide more background. But I pretty much like to know exactly what the code I write is doing and how much overhead I incur when using certain techniques. I really can't imagine not caring about stuff like this and am quite puzzled why some folks treat this type of question as off-limits.

Comment: @Alexander - Um I'm just trying to get an idea of how slow it is. Obviously if it's faster than the time spent waiting on IO, then you just use it. I'm not trying to speed up requests by not using async.

Comment: I applaud your curiosity, I’m disappointed that others are so quick to dismiss a valid question like this. But to your latter statement: It’s not faster, that’s certain. It’s actually doing strictly more work than doing the IO in the simple blocking way. It just happens to free up in the thread while it waits, that’s the advantage. So technically speaking, you can get infinitesimally lower latency with a blocking call, but at a much higher resource cost (a blocked thread)

Comment: @Alexander - Yes I get that part. I'm not worried about the slightly higher latency using await, because obviously scalability is more important. But if, lets say, using await causes an app thread to be busy for 10ms context switching while the IO itself is only 3ms, then you've made that request not only slower, but also made it use more thread resources than before. So it's counter-productive in every way. That is what I'm getting at.

Comment: @Ian indeed, makes sense!

Comment: @Alexander: I get the point of your connection pooling example, because it's counterintuitive. But no one in their right mind is thinking that networked database queries are fast. They're the bulkiest, most unwieldy thing we face on an everyday basis.

Comment: @Ian: I'm just trying to float an idea here, not make a judgment. Do you think there's an upper limit on how much you should care about small details before it becomes unproductive? What I'm trying to touch on here is the concept of micromanagement. Rereading your comment, can you sort of see how your argument is pretty much the kind of argument any micromanager would make to justify why they micromanage? I'm not saying this is definitely the case for you, but there's been a recurring response to this question in answers/comments that there's more productive fish to fry than async overhead.

Comment: @Flater - For argument's sake let's assume there is an average await overhead of 50ms and the majority of my DB queries only spend 1-5ms waiting on IO (as Azure indicates to me). For each request there could be several hits on the DB, and the overall execution time of a hello world requests sits at a couple ms. Changing over to await would drastically reduce your throughput for simple requests. Using await is simple in itself, but I am unable to determine whether I should be positive, negative, or neutral about its use for simple DB queries until I have an idea of the overhead.

Comment: @Flater That's true, although changing. More and more of the datastores I'm using on a day to day basis are non-relational, fully in-memory databases. Lord only knows what kind of swanky PCIe/DMA based networking trickery they're doing under the hood. Accessing my Memcached instances (technically a cache, but really that's just a kind of specialized database) has a latency of less than 2 ms, for example. Async/await might still be worth it, but I know that spinning up OS threads would not be worth it without pooling them, for example.

Comment: @Alexander: Async isn't really targeted at in-memory operations though.

Comment: It’s still over the network, but that’s kind of the point. Without knowing the overhead, you can’t judge when a workload is worth awaiting or blocking for. The 50 ms heuristic seems about right

Comment: A few things: 1. `Thread.Sleep` vs `Task.Delay` is not a fair comparison, because `Task.Delay` uses a timer, not a `Thread.Sleep` on another thread, consider doing that test instead.  2. the cited article that says 5ms is for .NET 4.5, there have been performance improvements since. 3. ValueTask can have less overhead in some situations.

Comment: @Theraot - Mind making that into an answer? It is approximately the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Overhead is less than 0.1 ms

*The rest of the answer is how I got that.*

I decided to introduce a version of the code that uses `Task.Run(()=> Thread.Sleep(waitTime))` which I consider a fairer comparison to simply sleep. So I have three versions.

I'm also compute how much time the code is not waiting. That is, I define how many iterations `profileIterations`, how much to wait `waitTime`, and then I multiply them so I know how much time is supposed to be expended waiting… Subtract that from the total time. Then I `profileIterations` so I know how much time is not waiting per iteration.

---

This is the code:

**Sleep version**

```
int profileIterations = 1000;
int waitTime = 5;
var timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
timer.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < profileIterations; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
}
timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine((timer.ElapsedMilliseconds - waitTime * profileIterations) / (double)profileIterations);
```

**Task.Run version**

```
int profileIterations = 1000;
int waitTime = 5;
var timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
timer.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < profileIterations; i++)
{
    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(()=> Thread.Sleep(waitTime));
}
timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine((timer.ElapsedMilliseconds - waitTime * profileIterations) / (double)profileIterations);
```

**Delay version**

```
int profileIterations = 1000;
int waitTime = 5;
var timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
timer.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < profileIterations; i++)
{
    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(waitTime);
}
timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine((timer.ElapsedMilliseconds - waitTime * profileIterations) / (double)profileIterations);
```

---

And these are the times:

- Sleep version: 10.605
- Task.Run version: 10.584
- Delay version: 10.814

*`Task.Run(()=> Thread.Sleep(waitTime))` appears to be faster than `Thread.Sleep(waitTime)`, which is nonsensical. This measurement is clearly wrong.*

Yeah, it is waiting around `15` to `16` milliseconds instead of `5` (it is waiting around `10` extra milliseconds). *Because time resolution is a thing. See [Can I improve the resolution of Thread.Sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614936/can-i-improve-the-resolution-of-thread-sleep)* So I tried with `waitTime = 16`, got these:

- Sleep version: 14.181
- Task.Run version: 14.82
- Delay version: 15.113

Now it is waiting about 30 milliseconds? Let us set `waitTime = 30`, got these:

- Sleep version: 1.288
- Task.Run version: 1.432
- Delay version: 1.561

Ha! - Let us do better. Change `timer.ElapsedMilliseconds` (`long`) to `timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds` (`double`), and we have better resolution.

Got these:

- Sleep version: 1.373*6827000000011*
- Task.Run version: 1.403*3598999999994*
- Delay version: 1.719*5541999999986*

*Not all of those digits are significant. Stopwatch can't report below 0.0001 milliseconds  (100 nanoseconds) in my computer.*

It appears that `Delay` is slower always. It is not a fair comparison anyway. Between the other two… This measurements suggest an overhead of 0.03 to 0.1 milliseconds from `Task.Run` and `await`.

---

Let us replace `Thread.Sleep` with `Thread.SleepWait`, this time we will have the thread spin!

This is the new code:

**SpinWait version**

```
int profileIterations = 1000;
int iterations = 1000;
var timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
timer.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < profileIterations; i++)
{
    Thread.SpinWait(iterations);
}
timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / (double)profileIterations);
```

**New Task.Run version**

```
int profileIterations = 1000;
int iterations = 1000;
var timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
timer.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < profileIterations; i++)
{
    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(()=> Thread.SpinWait(iterations));
}
timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds/ (double)profileIterations);
```

---

And these are the new results:

- SpinWait version: 0.041*0909*
- New Task.Run version: 0.053*339*

Increased to `iterations = 10000`, got these:

- SpinWait version: 0.389*3809*
- New Task.Run version: 0.408*0467*

That settles it for me. The overhead is between 0.01 and 0.02 milliseconds. Including both `Task.Run` and `await`.

*I tried increasing the iterations even more, and that gave me a larger overhead. I believe at that point I'm no longer measuring overhead but the interference of other processes. However, if you are curious, it only got up to 0.06 milliseconds. Which is still below the 0.1 milliseconds I got using Sleep.*

---

Finally, I want to mention that an async method that finished synchronously will have less overhead that one that did not. Similarly using `ValueTask` instead of `Task` can reduce overhead and allocations.

---

This tests were done in Windows 10, .NET 5.0, Intel I3. Oh, and using LINQPad. *Yeah, LINQPad.*

Comment: Yeah, tried same kinda thing with File IO. Results were pretty similar. Cost can only be tenths of ms at most.

Comment: @Ian Ok, that is another thing. IO task (file, network, etc...) are promise tasks. They setup an event that the OS calls when the operation is done. And the event handler will start the continuations of the task. Which is similar to Delay, actually, except there the event is a timer. As seen here Delay takes longer that Task.Run(Sleep), and that is not from async, await, or Task. It seems to be the event. I'd argue that this is the right way to do IO, because most of it will be some device using a buffer via DMA and not the CPU... Meanwhile the thread is free to do other stuff.

Comment: I agree. I think the old 50ms rule-of-thumb is completely invalid. Even if your DB reads are a couple ms, you still gain thread availability.